# Add Meta for Facebook with Custom Product Page

Tags: magento-1.9, facebook, meta

I have this custom product page but the meta information is not correct.

```
<?php    
$og = [];
$og['title'] = $this->getTitle();
$og['site_name'] = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
$og['description'] = strip_tags($this->getDescription());
$og['url'] = $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();

if(Mage::registry('current_product')):
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    $og['title'] = $product->getName();
    $og['type'] = 'product';
    $og['image'] = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(100,100);
    $og['description'] = strip_tags(($product->getShortDescription()));
    $og['price:amount'] = Mage::registry('product')->getFinalPrice();
    $og['price:currency'] = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
elseif(Mage::registry('current_category')):
    $og['type'] = 'product.group';        
elseif((Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home' &&
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms')) :
    $og['type'] = 'website';
else:
    $og['type'] = 'article';
endif;
?>
```

I use that code to Integrate the meta for check different kind of page in the Site. The code consider the Product as an Article Type.
According to the Facebook Share Debugger, it still a missing IMG.
[image]

And the page is considered to be an Article Type not a Product Type.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this snippet, that works on sites I´ve worked on and is build up a little different then the one you use right now.

Just give it a try maybe.

```
<?php if(Mage::registry('current_product')): ?>
 <?php $product = Mage::registry('current_product'); ?>
 <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo ($product->getName()); ?>" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="product" />
 <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(200,200);?>" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo Mage::registry('product')->getProductUrl(); ?>" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(($product->getShortDescription())); ?>" />
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); ?>" />
<?php elseif(Mage::registry('current_category')): ?>
 <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $this->getTitle() ?>" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="product.group" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); ?>" />
<?php elseif((Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home' &&
 Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms')) : ?>
 <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $this->getTitle() ?>" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); ?>" />
<?php else: ?>
 <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $this->getTitle() ?>" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: the only problem is that the code **if(Mage::registry('current_product'))** is not consider. the product page is being detect as "Article" mentioned on above post.

Comment: I updated it and you should try again

Answer (score 0):

You can **add** this snippet into  tag in **app/design/frontend/Theme_name/Theme_name/template/page/html/head.phtml**

```
<?php /* Open Graph Protocol for Facebook and SEO START */ ?>
<?php if(Mage::registry('current_product')): ?>
<?php $product = Mage::registry('current_product'); ?>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo ($product->getName()); ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(200,200);?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo Mage::registry('product')->getProductUrl(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(($product->getShortDescription())); ?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); ?>" />
<?php elseif(Mage::registry('current_category')): ?>
<?php $category = Mage::registry('current_category'); ?>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $this->getTitle() ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product.group" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); ?>" />
<?php elseif((Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home' &&Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms')) : ?>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $this->getTitle() ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($this->getDescription()) ?>" /><meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echoMage::app()->getStore()->getName(); ?>" />
<?php else: ?>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $this->getTitle() ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($this-> getDescription()) ?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
 <?php /* Open Graph Protocol for Facebook and SEO END */ ?>
```

It will surely help you.